# Scraping opensea with selenium, error: selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.webelement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

> CODE

```
website = 'https://opensea.io/collection/azuki?search[sortAscending]=false&search[sortBy]=FAVORITE_COUNT'

s= Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
see_more = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sc-1xf18x6-0 sc-1aqfqq9-0 haVRLx dfsEJr styledPhoenixText"]').click()

coll_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h1')
coll_desc1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '(//p[1])[1]')
coll_desc2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//p[2]')
coll_desc3 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//p[3]')
art_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sc-7qr9y8-0 sc-dw611d-1 iUvoJs fcpvjL"]')
art_price = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sc-7qr9y8-0 iUvoJs Price--amount"]')

collection_name = []
collection_desc1 = []
collection_desc2 = []
collection_desc3 = []
name = []
price = []

for c in coll_name:
    collection_name.append(c.text)
    time.sleep(1)


for d1 in coll_desc1:
    collection_desc1.append(d1.text)
    time.sleep(1)

for d2 in coll_desc2:
    collection_desc2.append(d2.text)
    time.sleep(1)
    
for d3 in coll_desc3:
    collection_desc3.append(d3.text)
    time.sleep(1)

for n in art_name:
    name.append(n.text)
    time.sleep(1)

for p in art_price:
    price.append(p.text)
    time.sleep(1)

Collection_Azuki = {'Collection_Name': coll_name, 'Collection_Description1': coll_desc1, 'Collection_Des2': coll_desc2, 'Colltionec_Des3': coll_desc3, 'Art_Name_fav': art_name, 'Art_Price_fav': art_price}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Collection_Azuki, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
df
```

> 1stly error : selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.webelement

> 2ndly, I want to get more than 6 results

> facing this error after program running

> XPATH Working well

[image: errorselenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.webelement]

> please help me solving these tow issues 1stly and 2ndly

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it doesn't look like error but maybe you forgot to use `()` or some function toget value from object - and this way it sends only information about object.

Comment: it would be easier if you create minimal working code - with imports - so we could simply copy and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong variables when you create `Collection_Azuki`

You use

```
'Collection_Name': coll_name
```

which means

```
'Collection_Name': driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h1')
```

but you should use

```
'Collection_Name': collection_name
```

which uses list created with `c.text`

The same with other variables in `Collection_Azuki`

---

You need

```
Collection_Azuki = {
    'Collection_Name': collection_name,
    'Collection_Description1': collection_desc1,
    'Collection_Des2': collection_desc2,
    'Colltionec_Des3': collection_desc3,
    'Art_Name_fav': name,
    'Art_Price_fav': price
}
```

Result:

```
   Collection_Name                                                          Collection_Description1 Collection_Des2 Colltionec_Des3 Art_Name_fav Art_Price_fav
0            Azuki  Take the red bean to join the garden. View the collection at azuki.com/gallery.                                  Azuki #8740            25
1             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #1948          2,61
2             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #4886            19
3             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #1889            12
4             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #8360            50
5             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #2362          2,94
6             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #4752        18,888
7             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #9024          4,07
8             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #5397         11,75
9             None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #4385            15
10            None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #5412           5,5
11            None                                                                             None            None            None  Azuki #3222          3,18
12            None                                                                             None            None            None         None            11
```